# Merge issue TFVC

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging, tfvc

In our team we got a problem involving merging/branching.
An abstraction of what happens:

1. FunctionA added to master
2. master branches to dev1 and dev2
3. FunctionA is removed from dev1, FunctionB added
4. FunctionC is added to dev2
5. Dev1 is merged into master
6. Problem: try to merge dev2 to master, VS merge tool thinks functionA is a new function

Due to this we currently need to manually merge every conflicted file. What would the best approach to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is this git hosted by TFS, or non-git TFS? (Just asking as “master” is a common git branch name, but not in TFS)

Comment: If this is git, have you considered rebasing dev2 onto the post-merge master instead?

Comment: It's TFVC, not git, apologies for the ambiguity.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Automatic merges aren't guaranteed, there will always be cases where you have to manually merge. It sounds like this is one of them.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way for dev2 to know functionA was deleted in dev1 without requiring manual merging. This causes mistakes like accidentally removing/adding required/redundant lines.

Comment: @JenseDf Yes, by merging from `dev1` into `dev2` after `dev1` was merged into `master`, but **before** merging from `dev2` into `master`.

Comment: @JenseDf That said - the best long-term solution would be to transition from TFS to git. Surprisingly TFS doesn't have a transition tool despite Microsoft being all pro-`git` since 2014, but I use `git-tfs` ( https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs ) whenever I need to do a transition and it's worked great for me.

Comment: I think you just answered my question, thanks! I will have a look to git-tfs, sure hope TFVC will go somewhat the same direction of git (or git to become the main VC of TFS).

Comment: @JenseDf  I've tried a similar structure, but didn't get conflict. But there is no Function A in master branch any more. Do you need Function A? You may check the branching strategies in TFVC to choose a property strategy for your team: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/effective-tfvc-branching-strategies-for-devops?view=azure-devops

Comment: That's odd, would the language matter? Using C++. The link has some really good advise, thank you.